# How to add a color picker to React Quill toolbar

Tags: reactjs, text-editor, rich-text-editor, react-quill

I want to use react-quill for my react rich text editor but I couldn't find a way to add a color picker in the toolbar.
I'm also using typescript.
here is my component:

```
const modules = {
  toolbar: [
    [{ font: ['', 'times-new-roman', 'arial'] }],
    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, false] }],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote'],
    [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }, { indent: '-1' }, { indent: '+1' }],
    ['link'],
    ['clean']
   
  ],
}
function RichTextEditor() {
  return <ReactQuill theme="snow" modules={modules} formats={formats} preserveWhitespace />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom toolbar with javascript like this, it might works!

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{
        header: [1, 2, false]
      }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block'],
      [{
        'color': ['#F00', '#0F0', '#00F', '#000', '#FFF', 'color-picker']
      }]
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow' // or 'bubble'
});

function showColorPicker(value) {
  if (value === 'color-picker') {
    var picker = document.getElementById('color-picker');
    if (!picker) {
      picker = document.createElement('input');
      picker.id = 'color-picker';
      picker.type = 'color';
      picker.style.display = 'none';
      picker.value = '#FF0000';
      document.body.appendChild(picker);

      picker.addEventListener('change', function() {
        quill.format('color', picker.value);
      }, false);
    }
    picker.click();
  } else {
    quill.format('color', value);
  }
}

var toolbar = quill.getModule('toolbar');
toolbar.addHandler('color', showColorPicker);
```

```css
#editor-container {
  height: 375px;
}

.ql-color .ql-picker-options [data-value=color-picker]:before {
  content: 'Pick Color';
}

.ql-color .ql-picker-options [data-value=color-picker] {
  background: none !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/katex.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/monokai-sublime.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="editor-container">
</div>
```

This is an example with javascript, you can convert into typescript if you want.
Thank you.

Comment: thank you! but is there any way to make this happen just using react's jsx? if not, is there any other library to do this more easily?

Comment: Not sure about the library, you can do it with javascript if you want. Please do upvote if you find it helpful.

Comment: i recommend using input event listener instead of change.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using a custom color picker which I open on the click
complete code here - https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/react-quill-example-5j6w2y?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A13%2C22

first you have to do this

```
#editor-container {
  height: 375px;
}

.ql-color .ql-picker-options [data-value=color-picker]:before {
  content: 'Pick Color';
}

.ql-color .ql-picker-options [data-value=color-picker] {
  background: none !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


 const modules = {
    toolbar: [
      [{ size: fontSizeArr }],
      [{ font: Font.whitelist }],
      [{ align: [] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
      ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
      [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
      [{ color: ['color-picker'] }, { background: ['color-picker'] }],
      ['link', 'image'],
      ['clean']
    ],

 {showColorPicker && (
        <div className=" absolute  right-[20%]   top-[5%] z-[100000] mt-4 flex flex-col items-center justify-center rounded border-[1px] border-bBlack-70 bg-tWhite-50 p-[4px]">
          <HexColorPicker color={selectedColor} onChange={(e) => setSelectedColor(e)} />
          <Button variant="primary" className="mt-1" onClick={applyColor}>
            Confirm
          </Button>
        </div>
      )}

  useEffect(() => {
    if (quillRef.current && showToolbar) {
      const quillInstance = quillRef.current.getEditor();
      const toolbar = quillInstance.getModule('toolbar');
      toolbar.addHandler('color', selectCustomColor);
      toolbar.addHandler('background', selectBackgroundCustomColor);
    }
  }, []);

  const applyColor = () => {
    const quillInstance = quillRef.current.getEditor();
    quillInstance.format('color', selectedColor);
    setShowColorPicker(false);
  };
```